# Can't cast base class object to derived type object, Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, casting

I understand that it is impossible in C#, but I need to do it somehow. I have two classes, a base class for list of flights.

```
public class Flight 
{
        [Key]
        public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
        public string CityOfArrival { get; set; }
        public string CityOfDeparture { get; set; }
        public char Terminal { get; set; }

        public FlightStatus Status { get; set; }
        public int Gate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }

        public double PriceForFirstClass { get; set; }
        public double PriceForBusiness { get; set; }
        public double PriceForEconom { get; set; }
}
```

And derived class for archive list of flights.

```
class ArchiveFlight :Flight
{
}
```

Here is my `DbContext` class.

```
 class FlightsDatabase : DbContext
 {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Flight>().HasMany(x => x.Passengers).
                WithOptional(x => x.Flight).HasForeignKey(x => x.flightNumber).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }

        public DbSet<Flight> Flights { get; set;}
        public DbSet<ArchiveFlight> FlightsArchive { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to do something like this.

```
flights.FlightsArchive.Add((ArchiveFlight)flightToclean);
flights.Flights.Remove(flightToclean);
```

Where `flightToclean` is type of `Flight`. `flights` is type of `FlightsDatabase` .

Can I do this shortly or do I need to create new `ArchiveFlight` object and copy all properties of `Flight` object to new `ArchiveFlight` object?

Comment: Typo alert: it's a **passenger** - not a "passanger"

Comment: You could make `ArchiveFlight` the base class. Or map CUD actions to stored procedures and in the delete procedure of a `Flight`, copy the deleted flight to the `ArchiveFlight` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you have `Flight` entity in your context, and a `FlightArchive` entity, and once a flight is done, you want to move that flight in the `FlightArchive` collection.

To achive this, the best solution will be to get rid of `FlightArchive` entity, and to create property of type `bool` in `Flight` model.

In this way you can set that property to true, once a flight is done(old). 
It will be more easy for future data manipulation.

so, in your :

```
  public class Flight 
    {
          ...
     public bool FlightArchive {get;set;}
    }
```

then, when the flight is done, you can do this:

```
var flight=_context.Flights.Find(flightId);
flight.FlightArchive =true;
```

when you need the flight list: you can do:

```
var flightList=_context.Flights.Any(x=>!x.FlightArchive).ToList()

var flightArchive=_context.Flights.Any(x=>x.FlightArchive).ToList();
```